# Kinetic.js don't lose grip on mouse out

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

When you drag an object and mouse is out of rendering area, dragging stops (firing an event) and user loses a grip.

It's extremelly inconvenient, taking into account that all other technologies (Flash, raw HTML5 Canvas, etc) allows to save the grip even if mouse is out.

Is there a way to solve the problem?

**UPDATE:** Up to the moment solved the problem by changing library file and binding listeners to the document, not to the container. I know that it's bad to hack into library files, but after inspecting the library's source code I haven't found out way around.

Answer (score 2):

you could check if the element is out of sight and if so bring it back:

```
shape.on('dragend', function() {
 var pos = shape.getPosition();
 var layer = pos.getLayer();
 if (pos.y < 0) {
  pos.y = 0;
 }
 var maxY = layer.getHeight() - shape.getHeight();
 if (pos.y > maxY) {
  pos.y = maxY
 }
 shape.setPosition(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`element.setCapture()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setCapture).  You can call it from within an event handler for a mouse event, eg. `mousedown`:

```
function mouseDown(e) {
    e.target.setCapture();
    e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, false);
}
```

Although browser support is a bit spotty (IE and Firefox support it, not sure about other browsers), for cross browser use you would have to fall back to the binding on the document approach you've already hit upon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Anyway I can learn from it for the future use!