# kinetic.js able to drag outside of stage?

Tags: kineticjs

Does anyone know if it is possible to set up kinetic.js so the user can drag outside of the stage? If the user mouses out of the stage they lose grip on the item as soon as the mouse leaves the stage area...this is annoying if you are dragging an image that is larger than the stage. (I'm setting up a cropping interface where they drag an image behind a mask to crop for a profile picture--similar to what twitter is doing).

I've searched around and can't find anything specific on how to fix this. Seems like someone else had a similar issue here and had to hack the source a bit to fix it: [Kinetic.js don't lose grip on mouse out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083960/kinetic-js-dont-lose-grip-on-mouse-out)

My thought would be to make the stage much larger than it currently is and set up a layer as the smaller masking area, but it would be more convenient if kineticjs just tracked mouse events even if the mouse left the stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to track the position of the mouse and use .simulate() to continue dragging objects even if mouse is outside of stage.
Or you could enlarge the stage once the mouse leaves it. 
But basically, your stage is a div/canvas, and it's limited to where you define it to be. Everything else is tricks to simulate its actions.